# Clang appears to be ignoring C++ version (std=gnu++14 and similar) under Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake, clang++

I'm developing on Mac OS 11.6.8, with Xcode 13.2.1 installed (but I'm working on the CMake-based project in VS Code). I've been baffled by loads of build errors such as:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:419:
[build] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:80:16: error: no template named 'unary_function'; did you mean 'binary_function'?
[build]         static unary_function<_Ap, _Rp>
```

I finally searched the whole project and determined that these must arise from Boost's use of **unary_function**, which was reportedly removed from C++ 17. But I'm specifying C++ 14 in my CMakeLists.txt, and indeed **std=gnu++14** is included in the Clang invocation, thanks to

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt.

A Web search on this error didn't reveal any solution, but it did turn up some comments asking whether Apple had broken pre-C++17 support somehow. I don't know how support for different C++ standards is implemented. Does SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 (from the error output) give a clue?

Here's the clang call:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -D_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC=0 -I/Users/me/data/series2server/include -I/Users/me/data/series2server/restbed/include -I/Users/me/data/series2server -I/Users/me/data/series2server/restbed_server/api -I/Users/me/data/series2server/restbed_server/model -g -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -pthread -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Series2Server.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/Series2Server.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/Series2Server.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/me/data/series2server/main.cpp
```

The Boost 1.80.0 files that use unary_function are:

```
functional.hpp
hash.hpp
logical.hpp
unique_ptr.hpp
```

Here's the stack of errors on Intel under OS 11.6.8:

```
In file included from /Users/me/data/series2server/main.cpp:3: THIS LINE SAYS #include <string>
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:511:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:179:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:652:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:206:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__debug:14:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:91:
In file included from /Users/me/data/series2server/restbed_server/model/time.h:24: THIS LINE SAYS #include <memory>
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:676:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:419:
.../MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:80:16: error: no template named 'unary_function'; did you mean 'binary_function'?
        static unary_function<_Ap, _Rp>
```

Here's the stack of errors on an M1 under OS 12.5.1:

```
In file included from /Users/me/data/series2server/main.cpp:3: THIS LINE SAYS #include<string>
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:519:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__debug:14:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:98:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__mbstate_t.h:29:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:123:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:91:
In file included from /Users/me/data/series2server/restbed_server/model/time.h:24: THIS LINE SAYS #include <memory>
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:674:
In file included from .../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:18:
.../MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/stdexcept:83:32: error: unknown type name 'string'
    explicit logic_error(const string&);
```

Final note: This turned out to be because a code generator create a file called Time.h, which apparently caused these errors; my guess is that there was a clash with a like-named file elsewhere.

Comment: Yes. I'm curious as to what is confusing, since I said "I'm specifying C++ 14 in my CMakeLists.txt, and indeed std=gnu++14 is included in the Clang invocation."

Comment: Can you not use 17 or greater?

Comment: @Taekahn As I noted: "these must arise from Boost's use of unary_function, which was reportedly removed from C++ 17"

Comment: @Oscar I’m rather shocked at the idea that it’s impossible to build boost under anything past 14. Are you using an old version of boost?

Comment: If you’re using the build In clang for Mac, I wouldn’t. I’d install it separately. I’ve heard it’s old and/or randomly janky

Comment: @Taekahn We're pulling the latest from https://github.com/boostorg

Comment: Does the error happen when clang is compiling main.cpp?

Comment: @273K It does. The complaints start in file included from main.cpp: #include <string>  Then it's a long chain of #includes within MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1, until we get to another one of my source files that has #include <memory>... then we're back into the SDK's memory -> iterator -> and finally c++/v1/__functional_base:80:16: error: no template named 'unary_function

Comment: Please pos a [mcve]. No cmake, just a small main.cpp and a single clang++ command.

Comment: All -I except -I/Users/me/data/series2server/include should not be used. Then time.h will not conflict.

Comment: Thanks, but series2server/include doesn't even exist. That's a vestige of when I started the project and expected to put stuff there. Time.h is in restbed_server/model.

Answer (score 1):

Either Boost our Apple SDK seem to be misconfigured. Boost can be compiled with C++17 for sure. If it's properly configured, Boost gets defined the macro `_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC=0` and successfully compiled with C++17. See for example [functional.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/boost/functional.hpp).

```
#if defined(_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC) && !_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC
        // std::unary_function and std::binary_function were both removed
        // in C++17.

        template <typename Arg1, typename Result>
        struct unary_function
        {
            typedef Arg1 argument_type;
            typedef Result result_type;
        };

        template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Result>
        struct binary_function
        {
            typedef Arg1 first_argument_type;
            typedef Arg2 second_argument_type;
            typedef Result result_type;
        };
#else
        // Use the standard objects when we have them.

        using std::unary_function;
        using std::binary_function;
#endif
```

You can add to the CMakeLists.txt

```
target_compile_definitions(${TARGET} _HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC=0)
```

Comment: Thanks much for that. I made sure that this flag was passed to everything being built: OpenSSL, a static HTTP server lib (open-source project called Restbed which uses ASIO from Boost), and finally this test application, which uses much more of Boost, statically links to Restbed and OpenSSL. No dice. I get the same errors as before, but different on my two systems (I pasted the errors above). There's clearly something profoundly wrong somewhere... but what?

Comment: I do not see any change in /usr/bin/clang++ command.

Comment: I didn't go back and replace the one in the original post. Doing that now...

Comment: You got other errors, not connected to Boost. /Users/me/data/series2server/restbed_server/model/time.h conflicts with the system time.h. -I should follow -isysroot. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Exactly. That's why this is so mystifying. Since I don't know where the problem originates, a "minimal reproducible example" is the entire project. Not sure I can post that.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the code in this project was generated from an OpenAPI document. One of the generated classes was called Time. Despite it being couched in several nested namespaces, at some point it appears to have caused confusion with some other Time class or file and led to these obscure errors.

Renaming the Time schema in the OpenAPI document and then regenerating the classes appears to have resolved these problems.

Thanks for all the feedback.